# many-2-many with parquet_fdw

Tags: postgresql

1. postgres wont allow to invoke more then one server on the same data directory
2. postgres wont allow to invoke a server on more then one data directory

is it possible to solve those 2 requirements by using parquet_fdw ?
** I only need to read and never write etc** except of course when first loading data.

parquet_fdw does not require to invoke a new server so i can have multiple different parquet files and different servers trying to "mount" them.

i tried on a small example and it worked.

for requirement #1, suppose i invoke 5 servers on same parquet file, is it guarantee that those servers wont write (hint bits etc) to the parquet file and only read? i mean is it possible to put the parquet file on a WORM (write once read many) device ?

thanks

Comment: I have not the faintest clue what you want to do. Can you explain with some more technical detail? You can start only one postmaster on a data directory, but you can have many concurrent database sessions.

Comment: Suppose i have lots of linux machines working on NFS but those machines lacks cores. instead of invoking one post master and run concurrent sessions on the same data, i can run postmasters on 100 machines on the same data  increasing my performance

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot start more than one postmaster on a single data directory. That would result in instant data corruption.

If you want to scale reads horizontally, use streaming replication. That will scale much better than shared storage anyway, because you won't be bounded by the single I/O system.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. What about FDW with parquet ? Not data directory

Comment: What is the benefit over having a single monolithic PostgreSQL server with storage striped over several devices?

Comment: Distributing the storage is an overhead for me. i have thousands of users generating new content trying to analyze it using PG. Our users invoke our app (using PG as backend) and once our app finishes, the postmaster dies with it. We dont have dedicated servers for PG. The content lifetime does not need to be long. my main focus is to be fast and paying the extra time for replication is waste because this data wont last and because new users will need to get new copies.

Comment: Also i would like to add that each time only several users that are not aware of each other will probably query the data so IO bottleneck is not my main concern

Comment: Then PostgreSQL is the wrong choice for you. Use an embedded database like SQLite.